# Can I control the insert/update-command of (fluent) nhibernate to call a webservice instead of writing into the DB?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I want to use fluent-nhibernate to query my data, but when a entity gets saved, it should not be written into the database via insert/update. Instead, I want to (better: have to) serialize that object and send it to a webservice (which will map that object to a 3rd-party class that will trigger some important business-logic).

Is such behaviour possible to implement with nhibernate (call a custom method instead of update on saving)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to use a SaveOrUpdateEventListener for this task.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a IRepository interface and hiding the webservice and Nhibernate functionality behind that. You could possibly use NHibernate interceptors for this, but it doesn't sound like a clean solution. Personally, I would hate to find Web service code hidden in one of Nhibernate interceptors.